# Puppeteer Error: error while loading shared libraries: libgobject-2.0.so.0

Tags: docker, puppeteer, nestjs, google-cloud-run

I have a NestJS App deployed on Google Cloud Run which is using puppeteer (V7.0.1) to generate a PDF. Locally, everything is working absolutely fine, but on my Cloud Run Service I keep getting the following error:
`/usr/app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-848005/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libgobject-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

The directory does exist in the Docker container (checked with `RUN ls node_modules/.....`).
Using the Docker code from the [puppeteer troubleshooting doc](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md) or any other snippet I found on similar issues on the web result in the same error for me.

#### Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12-slim AS base
WORKDIR /usr/app

FROM base AS build
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn --prod
COPY . ./
RUN yarn add @nestjs/cli
RUN yarn sass && yarn build && yarn copy-pdf-assets

FROM base
COPY --from=build /usr/app ./
ENV PATH /usr/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
CMD yarn start:prod
```

#### Generate PDF Function:

```
//also tried headless: true or false and many other flags that deemed to fix it for others
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] }); 

try {
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setViewport({ height: 792, width: 1039 })
    await page.setContent(this.getTemplate(template, data), {
        waitUntil: ['load', 'domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0']
    });
    await page.addStyleTag({ path: this.resolvePath(`/templates/${template}/styles.css`) })

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));

    return await page.pdf({ format: 'a4', landscape: true, printBackground: true });
} finally {
    await browser.close();
}
```

Let me know if you need any other information.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To anyone reading this with a similar problem and setup: my mistake was the build step in my docker file. Since I was installing chromium there, instead of the actual run step, puppeteer actually didn't have a chromium instance while running. I just moved the apt-get stuff to the last step of my docker file, that fixed it.

Edit 2023-05-23:

Working version of above dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12-slim AS base
WORKDIR /usr/app

FROM base AS build
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn --prod
COPY . ./
RUN yarn add @nestjs/cli
RUN yarn sass && yarn build && yarn copy-pdf-assets

FROM base
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY --from=build /usr/app ./
ENV PATH /usr/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
CMD yarn start:prod
```

Comment: Can you add the final version of your docker file?

Comment: @gandalf I added the code, as stated in the answer: Just had to move the chromium install to the last step

Comment: Chiming in in 2024, I can confirm that having these install steps as your last RUN command works! Also fwiw here is the official 'troubleshooting' doc from the puppeteer team on how to install chromium for puppeteer within a Dockerfile: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker