# Puppeteer Failed to launch chrome , error while loading shared libraries

Tags: node.js, linux, puppeteer, chromium, redhat

Error: Failed to launch chrome! /node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-662092/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libXcomposite.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer Error: error while loading shared libraries: libgobject-2.0.so.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66070860/puppeteer-error-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgobject-2-0-so-0)

Answer (score 0):

Download the libraries in a directory and install the same. One can directly install it. I had to move the libraries to prod server, so downloaded it.

> yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=puppetterlib pango.x86_64
> libXcomposite.x86_64 libXcursor.x86_64 libXdamage.x86_64
> libXext.x86_64 libXi.x86_64 libXtst.x86_64 cups-libs.x86_64
> libXScrnSaver.x86_64 libXrandr.x86_64 GConf2.x86_64 alsa-lib.x86_64
> atk.x86_64 gtk3.x86_64 ipa-gothic-fonts xorg-x11-fonts-100dpi
> xorg-x11-fonts-75dpi xorg-x11-utils xorg-x11-fonts-cyrillic
> xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 xorg-x11-fonts-misc -y

Traverse to the directory and install it

> sudo rpm -Uvh *.rpm

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but this is how i solved this problem in 2024 Jan:

- My option is to use `chromium-headless` instead

### Build Docker image

**1. Info:**

- os: `MacOS`
- Image builder: `rhel9/nodejs-18-minimal` - tag: `1:89`, `1:93`, `1:103`
- Chromium-headless packages:

  --> epel-9 (option):
  https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-9.noarch.rpm

  --> chromium-common (required):
  https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/chromium/120.0.6099.224/1.el9/x86_64/chromium-common-120.0.6099.224-1.el9.x86_64.rpm

  --> chromium-headless (required):  https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/chromium/120.0.6099.224/1.el9/x86_64/chromium-headless-120.0.6099.224-1.el9.x86_64.rpm

**2. Dockerfile**

> builder stage

---

`FROM registry.redhat.io/rhel9/nodejs-18-minimal:latest AS builder`

`... build your nodejs application ...`

---

> runer stage

`FROM registry.redhat.io/rhel9/nodejs-18-minimal:latest AS runer`

`USER root`

`RUN microdnf install dnf -y && dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-9.noarch.rpm -y && dnf install https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/chromium/120.0.6099.224/1.el9/x86_64/chromium-common-120.0.6099.224-1.el9.x86_64.rpm -y && dnf install https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/chromium/120.0.6099.224/1.el9/x86_64/chromium-headless-120.0.6099.224-1.el9.x86_64.rpm -y`

`COPY --from=builder ...`

`CMD [...]`

---

**3. Chromium-headless executable path**

Start your Puppeteer with this path:

```
const executablePath = "/usr/lib64/chromium-browser/headless_shell";
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--disable-extensions"],
  headless: true,
  args: [
    "--no-sandbox",
    "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
    "--no-zygote",
    "--disable-web-security",
    "--disable-gpu",
    // ...
  ],
  executablePath: executablePath,
});
```

**4. Smile :)**